# Bug in calculating reputation for day/week

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/2448/stackv.png

Reputation points for 'today' is 20 for the week is 19. I didn't receive any down mods yesterday so it can't be subtracting 1 for that. I think there might me a calculation error here.

---

from [**balexandre**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28004/balexandre) (*so I don't need to open up another question, but want to show my image regarding the same issue*)

I have the exact same thing today:

[image]

one says 25, other 15 :-/

Is there a sync problem today?

Comment: Did you downvote someone's answer during that time?

Comment: Yeah but I don't think that was my last reputation changing activity but I might be wrong because I don't know exactly what timezone stack operates and it is possible the 'stack' day ended a little after the down mod. If that is the case then I would suggest there should be an option to view the changes in reputation for every action. Apologies, I'm a little pedantic

Comment: The day changes over at 00:00 UTC.  Go to the reputation tab on your profile page and click `By Time`.

Comment: If you click on your username at the top and get the dropdown, it gives the current time in UTC, so you can figure out the difference between that and your current time.

Comment: I did that but it does not show any down votes i.e. posts which I have down voted but it does reflect my posts that have been down voted.

Comment: The labels say `downvoted` for other's posts that you have downvoted, and `downvote` for your posts on which you have received downvotes.  Have you gone to the `/reputation` page and done a recalc lately?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is recalc, I mean where is such an option but I'm posting a screenshot of my reputation page with info from last 2 days. I fail to notice a negative in that http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/9655/repua.png

Comment: Yes, I see.  You are correct about that.  To do a recalc, go to stackoverflow.com/reputation and scroll to the bottom.  See if the number it has there matches your current reputation.  If not, hit recalc, go back twice, and reload the page.

Comment: The reputation points are equal now day:week but On stackoverflow.com/reputation I didn't see an entry for 29 and 28 August although I was active then, I'm just curious

Comment: You've got me, then.  See if someone else has some insight.

Comment: Just added my own image of the same problem ... it's weird the out-of-sync part :-/ --> http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2011-08-30_1029.png

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved with [the most recent reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), these totals will have complete (and matching) explanations in your profile.